# Odoo v10: What is sudo() and SUPERUSER_ID?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

Can we change the method `sudo()` or the variable `SUPERUSER_ID` in order to get the current user instead of Administrator every time?

Answer (score 0):

In case of `SUPERUSER_ID`, that's a fixed variable. You could modify it in the file `__init__.py` of the openerp folder of OCB:

```
SUPERUSER_ID = 1  # Put any ID you want
```

Of course I don't recommend you to do that. If you want to get the current UID, do this, if it's possible:

```
self.env.user.id
```

But, in case of `sudo()`, you can do what you want with no problem. Just send to the method the ID of the current user as an argument, like this:

```
xxx.sudo(self.env.user.id).xxx()
```

However, you know that any action is performed by the current user, unless you apply the method `sudo()` to make the action be performed by other user different from the current one. What I want to say is that if you do nothing, the actions are performed by the current user, you don't need to use `sudo()` for that.

Comment: `self.env.user.id` still give the Administrator, instead of the current user

Comment: Are you writing that `self.env.user.id` inside a method called with `sudo()`? Because if you do that, you'll always get the UID 1, it doesn't matter if your current user isn't the *Administrator*.

Comment: No, i'm not using sudo(). I tried another expression to get the current user which is: `request.session.uid`. This one gives me the current user id, but then when i try to send an email to current user email, the email is being sent to Administrator email. It's like it's always looking at Administrator as the current user even when other users are logged in.